# How to check if Number TextEdit is empty?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, is-empty

so I have this problem where I am trying to make Random Number Generator app on android. Basically you set the minimum and the maximum number and then it randomly picks numbers between min and max.
However my problem comes if the min or max TextEdit field is empty, the app crashes. I would like to display "X" on the screen. How to check if the field is empty or not?
I am using kotlin and here is sample of my code. I am begginer so please do not flame me if the code is wrong :)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rollButton)
    val resultsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultsTextView)
    //val seekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
    val min = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.number_min)
    val max = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.number_max)




    rollButton.setOnClickListener {

    if(min.text.toString().toInt()>= 0 && max.text.toString().toInt() <= 1000){
        val rand = Random.nextInt(min.text.toString().toInt(),max.text.toString().toInt()+1)
        resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
    }
        else if(min.text.toString().isNullOrBlank()){
        resultsTextView.text = "X"


    }
        else{

        resultsTextView.text = "X"
    }

    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if your EditText is empty use `isNullOrEmpty()`. This will check if your field is empty or is null, like the method name says. Here is an example:

```
val editTextString :String = editText.text.toString()
if(!editTextString.isNullOrEmpty()) //returns true if string is null or empty
```

There is another approach with `TextUtils` but since you are using `Kotlin` this approach is better.

**EDIT:**

You are doing this:

```
if(min.text.toString().toInt()>= 0 && max.text.toString().toInt() <= 1000){
        val rand = Random.nextInt(min.text.toString().toInt(),max.text.toString().toInt()+1)
        resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
}
```

and here this line `min.text.toString().toInt()` is throwing you an exception. The reason for this is because currently `min` or `max` are empty `String`. So compailer can't format number from an `String equals to ""`. You should do it like this:

```
if(!min.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty() && !max.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty() && min.text.toString().toInt()>= 0 && max.text.toString().toInt() <= 1000){
        val rand = Random.nextInt(min.text.toString().toInt(),max.text.toString().toInt()+1)
        resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
}
```

I hope this works. If not, then take this into two IF statements like this:

```
if(min.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty() || max.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty() {
         resultsTextView.text = "X"
} else if(min.text.toString().toInt() >= 0 && max.text.toString().toInt() <= 1000) {
         val rand = Random.nextInt(min.text.toString().toInt(), max.text.toString.toInt()+1)
         resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
}
```

The second approach is maybe an even better and cleaner version since you don't have to check for anything else later.

Comment: So I modified my code but the app still keeps crashing. Could the code be wrong in any other way? Now it looks like this: `val min = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.number_min)
            else if(!min.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty()){
            resultsTextView.text = "X"
        }`

Comment: Can you please give me your exception? What error does it show when the app crashes?

Comment: I wanted to post the code here, but it says it is too long for a comment so there is a screenshot of the code I've posted on Imgur: https://imgur.com/3166tn5

Comment: You have another issue. On your line 24 in MainActivity, it says this: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "". So you are trying to format a number from an empty string as much as I can tell. So it could be your if statement or? Maybe you didn't check for your first IF that min or max is null or empty?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and knowledge. It finally works :) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!

Comment: You might want to use ``isNullOrBlank`` which is like ``isNullOrEmpty`` except it counts whitespace too. Or it's good to know it's there, anyway!

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks man, or maybe to use trim() to get rid of spaces.